# Load SharePoint List data on a page without having permission on a list using Javascript REST Api

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Here in this javascript i loaded all the items id of SharePoint list "XYZ" in a dropdown box.
I have removed User "Manoj" from list permission but it has permission on a page where i put this javascript using content editor.
Now when i access this page using Site Administrator then i can see the list items id in drop down but when i move on next user "Manoj" who does not have permission on List but have on page than it's give me message like
**"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."**

So my question is can we load data of list in a Web-Part page in which user don't have permission in list but have full permission on a page? i am asking this question because i don't give user to permission to see the list and perform operation if user want to add or edit data only by using web part page.

If not then is there any other way like: Using javascript change the user on Page load.

Below is javascript rest api that i used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( window ).load(function() {
DisplayItem();
});
function DisplayItem(){

 var requestUri = 'http://abc/pharma/Zdus/RnD/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle(\'XYZ\')/items'
 var requestHeaders = {
 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
 }; 
 $.ajax({
 url: requestUri, 
 dataType: "json", 
 type: 'GET',
 headers: requestHeaders,
success: function(json) {
var len= (json.d.results.length);
var x=document.getElementById("myList");
for (var i=0;i<len;i++)
{
var nid=(json.d.results[i].ID);
x.options[x.options.length] = new Option(nid, nid);
}
}, 
 error: function(error){
 alert(error.responseText);
 }
 });
}
</Script>
<div>
<label>Total Items</label>
       <select id="myList" >
        <option value=''></option>
</select>
```

Any help highly appreciated.
Not: This working fine with Site Admin and the Users who has list permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load or get data from Sharepoint if user does not have permission on that list.

To fetch the data from Sharepoint Atleast read permission is required. You can give only read permission to the user.

Comment: Hi Aanchal Firstly thanks for your reply but here i want to perform CRUD operation when user select id from the DropDown then in one <div> html form displayed and in that user can add or edit the item from SharePoint List.

Comment: Then you have to provide the user with contribute permissions. Or if you are using code-behind for this you can use runwithelevatedprivileges delegate method.

Comment: so can we used runwithelevatedprivileges delegate in javascript Rest-Api if yes than can you provide me good example link or any else that might helpful for me.

Comment: No. we can not use this in javascript api. You have to provide the permissions otherwise there would be security loop hole that any one perform CRUD operation on list.